# Send message to single client in tomcat websockets

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat7, java-ee-7

In tomcat-8 examples I have seen a example on chat using HTML5 web sockets.

The code is shown below

```
public class ChatAnnotation {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ChatAnnotation.class);

private static final String GUEST_PREFIX = "Guest";
private static final AtomicInteger connectionIds = new AtomicInteger(0);
private static final Set<ChatAnnotation> connections =
        new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

private final String nickname;
private Session session;

public ChatAnnotation() {
    nickname = GUEST_PREFIX + connectionIds.getAndIncrement();
}


@OnOpen
public void start(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
    connections.add(this);
    String message = String.format("* %s %s", nickname, "has joined.");
    broadcast(message);
}


@OnClose
public void end() {
    connections.remove(this);
    String message = String.format("* %s %s",
            nickname, "has disconnected.");
    broadcast(message);
}






    @OnMessage
          public void incoming(String message) {
       // Never trust the client
        String filteredMessage = String.format("%s: %s",
            nickname, HTMLFilter.filter(message.toString()));
         broadcast(filteredMessage);
    }


 private static void broadcast(String msg) {
      for (ChatAnnotation client : connections) {
          try {
              synchronized (client) {
                  client.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
              }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              log.debug("Chat Error: Failed to send message to client", e);
              connections.remove(client);
              try {
                  client.session.close();
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                // Ignore
             }
              String message = String.format("* %s %s",
                     client.nickname, "has been disconnected.");
             broadcast(message);
           }
      }
  }
  }
```

This code send a message to all the clients who connected to server .
But I want to send message to only "Guest1".
I think for loop has to be change.
How to send message to only "Guest1".

Comment: Did You even try to do this ?

Comment: @endriu_l yeah I tried but failed every time

Comment: OK...so what was the problem? You have a loop that sends message to everyone one by one, just pick one client and send the message only to him

Comment: @endriu_l How to write such a loop

Comment: but You already have it...in `broadcast` method

Comment: you can break the loop on first iteration. just put break; after client.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);

Answer (score -1):

Convert connections from set into a map:

```
ConcurrentHashMap< String, ChatAnnotation> connections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Keep user or whatever identifier you have to identify user as key in the map. They get the connection object from map using user key in broadcast method and send message only to that user, instead of iterating over all connection objects.